# Every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of open intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of open intervals.

We know that $\mathbb R$ is second countable that is it has  a countable base $\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$

hence If $O$ is an open set then $O=\cup_{a,b\in \mathbb Q}(a,b)$

hence it is expressible as a countable union of open intervals

Is this arguement right?

Comment: How do you know the countable base consists of open intervals?

Comment: Yeah first line is a bit backwards. Surely $\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ is what tells us $\mathbb R$ is second-countable, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Besides, $\mathbb R$ having a countable base $\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$ is basically the whole proof. You can't just state that.

Comment: You can't say $\mathcal O = \cup_{a,b\in\mathbb Q}(a,b)$.  You need something like: for each $x\in O$ there are rationals $a,b$ s.t. $x\in(a,b)\subseteq \mathcal O$.  Write $\mathcal O$ as a union of those intervals and argue there are only countably many different ones since $a,b\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Is it possible you meant to ask about every open set in $\Bbb R$ being a countable union of **pairwise disjoint** open intervals?  Because this is also true.

Comment: @user46944 That can be deduced from the given proposition, although that is the form I expected. Regardless, the proof is still going to be pretty much the same.

Comment: @veltas What? Please show me how the proof will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $\mathcal B$ is a base of topology $\mathcal O$ then:
$$O\in\mathcal O\iff O=\cup\{B\in\mathcal B\mid B\subseteq O\}$$
If $\mathcal B$ is countable then $\cup\{B\in\mathcal B\mid B\subseteq O\}$ is a countable union of sets that are elements of base $\mathcal B$.